# Predictive Modeling - Software Best Practice

Tags: r, data-mining

I would like to know what are the best practices for building Predictive Modeling solutions organically ?
Some of the questions I have are :-

- If I have multiple R model files, what are efficient ways of storing them ?

  - Save as .Rdata files on file system
  - Serialize to a DB as binary objects
- Since data is processed to create an interim model specific format, is it helpful to use such paradigms as PMML ?
- Also, should one consider such practices as MVC (I'm not a trained software developer, so any insights into such development practices would be very helpful)

I apologize for the open-ended nature of this question. I wish to understand even simple things as recommended folder structure for data staging, model store, scripts collection and such other elements of a data mining solution.

I would be very grateful to members of the community for sharing their experiences and recommendations.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Regarding work flow - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429907/workflow-for-statistical-analysis-and-report-writing

Comment: From statistical point of view, you better check elsewhere. From a programming point of view, following questions are also covering this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266279/how-to-organize-large-r-programs , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712421/r-and-version-control-for-the-solo-data-analyst , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860314/essential-skills-of-a-data-scientist , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097598/version-control-for-one-man-project-using-eclipse , ...

Comment: To the OP: This is a pretty good question as questions go in general, but giving a useful detailed response takes a lot of effort.  That makes it a difficult question to do on SO.